# java beginner wants to learn Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm  a rookie in *Java*, so far I have completed the core *Java* concepts except the *IO* chapter. I planning to finish up the *J2EE* material and frameworks such as *Hibernate*, *Spring* and *Struts*.

Please guide me. How can I finish up studying *Hibernate*, *Springs* and *Struts* in 2 days without going through *J2EE* in detail .Since I'm preparing for an interview?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have not become a master in Hibernate by now, I remember  http://mavenedge.com guys used to provide free instructor-led online training on Hibernate, Spring and stuff to a limited number of students. See if they're still doing that.

Answer (score 9):

I doubt anyone could take on that material in two days and be able to make sense in an interview. A smart interviewer will rapidly establish that you have only read some books and really don't know that much.

The best thing to do (in my opinion) is read the websites for spring and hibernate to get an idea of what they do at a conceptual level. Then in the interview don't try and hide your lack of knowledge. But talk about how fast you can learn, how eager you are to use these tools and how much you want to work with other developers to build systems.

Honesty and a good attitude in an interview will get you further than trying to fake your way through.

Answer (score 2):

you can get some hibernate here: [The Easiest Way To Learn Hibernate: YouTube Videos and the Online Tutorial](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=60191)

Comment: +1, just saw this on TSS and was about to post it :)

Answer (score 1):

REMEMBER, Technical Knowledge is an ocean, you cant get any thing within 2 days or 3 days. You need to apply yourself and learn.

Since i can understand what kind of situationa are you in I can put some points for you

1)My Personnel Opinion, if you are aware of the JDBC, then you can corelate with the Hiberante and Leanr more quickly.
So you get the basic Hibernate Topics!!!!
2) Check for the Video Tutorials in Videos.google.com or Youtube.com, this will defnitely Help, even for me when i was learning it helped me a lot to understand better
3)After that You try to complete Struts or Spring either one is sufficient I dont think you can focus both in 2 days, you can say that you got a chance to work only on Struts /Spring

Hope this work

Answer (score 0):

There's a series of "#{name_of_framework} in action" books you could read. There's one for hibernate, spring and struts each (actually when I read them it was webwork, the precursor of struts, but they probably updated it). But I don't think 2 days will be enough to go through them (and actually remember anything).
You could also try doing some basic tutorials, but still that's barely scratching the surface. Hopefully your potential employer realizes that they can teach you some of the more advanced stuff there (especially since you'll probably have to get used to the way they use these frameworks)